# p-adic analogue of octonions

Tags: nt.number-theory, finite-fields, projective-geometry, p-adic-numbers, octonions

There are the complex p-adic numbers.
But what is the p-adic analogue of the Cayley–Dickson construction?
Or more important: What is the p-adic analogue of the octonions?
It would be nice if the (unit)-multiplication table of such a p-adic analogue corresponds to the projective plane over the finite field with p elements.
Is there any interesting mathematical structure with such a multiplication table for a general p?
Is there any research work about this?

Comment: The Cayley–Dickson construction makes sense starting from any (possibly non-associative) $*$-algebra over a ring: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction#General_Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction so presumably one would need to take the $\mathbb{C}_p$ and just run the machine. I'm not sure what you mean by the next bit.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Surely this is a reference to the relation between the multiplication table of the standard basis of the octonions and the geometry of the projective plane over $\mathbb F_2$ (there is one non-$1$ basis vector for each point, and $e_i \cdot e_j = \pm e_k$ where $i,j,k$ are colinear.) I would guess division algebras with a similar relationship to projective planes over larger finite fields are known not to exist, but this isn't based on any hard evidence.

Comment: @WillSawin aha, that's what "(unit)-multiplication table" means!

Comment: Already the issue of quaternion algebras extending the $p$-adics is subtle, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_algebra#Classification. The reference here https://mathoverflow.net/a/283222/4177 might be of some use

Comment: There is a discussion about the division algebra case:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321453/what-are-the-p-adic-division-algebras                                                                                                                        https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406381/is-there-a-classification-of-the-p-adic-normed-division-algebras                  
For the octonionic case i found this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96429/matrix-representation-of-octonions/1391156

Comment: I never heard "complex $p$-adic numbers" for $\mathbf{C}_p$ although I now can see [Planetmath advertises this definition](https://planetmath.org/complexpadicnumbers#:~:text=The%20field%20of%20complex%20p,absolute%20value%20%7C%E2%8B%85%7Cp%20.). This is only partially an analogy. For $p$ such that $-1$ is not a square, one could also define "complex $p$-adic numbers" as $\mathbf{Q}_p[\sqrt{-1}]$. Or even any quadratic extension of $\mathbf{Q}_p$. This is closer to question of asking about a 8-dimensional non-associative algebra with given properties.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Defining and classifying the octonion algebras (composition algebras of dimension $8$) over fields $k$, or, in more sophisticated terms, computing the Galois cohomology set $H^1(k, G_2)$, is the topic of the book *Octonions, Jordan Algebras and Exceptional Groups* by T. A. Springer & F. D. Veldkamp (2000, appropriately published by Springer).  Among other things, after properly defining what this means, they explain (§1.10(vi), page 22) that over the $p$-adic fields, just like over the finite fields or totally imaginary number fields, every octonion algebra is split, meaning it is isomorphic to the obvious one.

[These notes by P. Gille](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/homes-www/gille/prenotes/octonions_beamer.pdf) discussing the more general problem of the classification of octonion algebras over rings, might also be worth looking at.